# How to define weights for KNN?

Tags: matlab, machine-learning, knn, euclidean-distance

I want to identify a set of weights for the distance measure in KNN method. I read through the MATLAB help and I found that there are functions for inverse or squared inverse (w.r.t the distances) weights however a user defined weights must be a function of the form: `@ fnc`
where

> `fcn` is a function that accepts a matrix of nonnegative distances, and returns a matrix the same size containing nonnegative distance weights. For example, `inversesquared` is equivalent to `@(d)d.^(-2)`.

I had defined the function to provide a random set of weights:

```
function WGT=gene 
weights=round(rand(a,b))
WGT=T
end
```

However, when I apply KNN the weights does not changed and are equally distributed.

Answer (score 0):

Does your fitting code look like `ClassificationKNN.fit(x, y, 'DistanceWeight', gene_weights)`? For example, I think what you mean above is

```
function w = gene_weights(x)
    w = round(rand(size(x)));
end
```

Or more compactly, you can just specify `gene_weights = @(x) round(rand(size(x)));`

Comment: Hi Max, thank you for your reply. My fitting code is (fitness=ClassificationKNN.fit(train_attribute,train_class,'Numneighbors',4,'distanceweight',@gene_weights)) and it produce an identical set of weights. I had removed the "@" and add the function to the main program but still the weights are the same, as if it didn't entered the function.

Comment: Hello. I have categoric datasets, Can I use that code for my categoric dataset? thanks